# Convert 3D data format to 4D in Keras / CNN

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have this error related to input shape:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_21 is incompatible with the
> layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received:
> (None, 2, 1)

Where is the problem in my code? In other words, how can I convert my 3d data into 4d format to enter to CNN network??

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)   
#print(len(y_train))
#print(len(y_test))

x_tra = np.array(X_train)
y_tra = np.array(y_train)

x_tst = np.array(X_test)
y_tst = np.array(y_test)

#print(x_tra.shape)
#print(y_tra.shape)
#print("*****************")
#print(x_tst.shape)
#print(y_tst.shape)

# Reshaping the data so it corresponds to the input format of keras
# Keras is developed for image analysis so the 1 basically means 1 color channel
X_train_reshaped = x_tra.reshape((x_tra.shape[0], x_tra.shape[1], 1))
X_test_reshaped = x_tst.reshape((x_tst.shape[0], x_tst.shape[1], 1))

print(X_train_reshaped.shape)
print(X_test_reshaped.shape)

# CNN Building

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding='valid', input_shape=(X_train_reshaped.shape),
                    activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train_reshaped, y_tra,
      batch_size=10, epochs=5,
      validation_data=(X_test_reshaped, y_tst))
```

Comment: If you're trying to provide some kind of sequence to your model as an input ( which has shape `( 2 , 1 )`, you can consider using `Conv1D` instead of `Conv2D`.

Comment: Thanks, the CNN has building......but, another problem exist in model.fit line and system not train data.